# Mattermost not sending verification email (but does send password reset)

Tags: mattermost

So I can reset my password but never get the verification emails. I tried the old link I got months ago, but that doesn't work anymore.

Username is

Comment: Hey Corey - I’ve deleted your personal email address from your question. And will post your question in infrastructure channel on Mattermost for you.

Comment: Thanks Karin. I'm not so worried about my email being listed publicly - I list it on my own website

Comment: Just following up on this, as I haven't been able to get in still @KarinG-SemperIT